# Passing Props in Global Components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to register a component globally while passing some properties, so i can call it anywhere in the page but it seems its not working unless i use inline templates.

I don't want an inline template i want to organize my global component into single directory

```
import asidecomponent from '@/components/partial/reusable-components/aside-components'

    Vue.component('aside-component', asidecomponent, {
      props: {
        formType: Boolean,
        message: String
      }
    })


  <aside-component formType="true" message="Foo Bar"></aside-component>
```

but i can't make this thing work any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Sharing them could help.

Comment: There's an error that says " Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Answer (score 6):

I think the declaration of your component is wrong. To extend your component definition with the added props, you can use the `extends` property.

```html
Vue.component('aside-component-with-props', {
  extends: asideComponent,
  props: {
    formType: Boolean,
    message: String
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `v-bind` method to typecast its value:

```
 <aside-component :formType="true" :message="'Foo Bar'"></aside-component>
```

Where you can see:

```
:formType="true" => passed as boolean
:message="'Foo Bar'" => passed as string (notice to the quote)
```

For message, you can also use as before as it's just a string.

---

From the error you mentioned `"Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"`,

I just noticed that you're not initializing the value. You should be validating props like this:

```
props: {
  formType: {
     type: Boolean,
     default: false // or set true
  }
  message: {
     type: String,
     default: '' // whatever you want as default
  }
}
```

So, you should notice here that we're initializing the default value. Now, your error should disappear and work fine.

Ah, and yes, you also need to use extend method for props to work:
So, replace this:

```
Vue.component('aside-component', asidecomponent, {
```

With this:

```
Vue.component('aside-component', Vue.extend(asidecomponent), {
```

See issue [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3039).